# How to load only version of Powershell module that I need and skip autoloading of other versions?

Tags: powershell, module

This subject is discussed many times and I read plenty of responses, but still cannot make mine to work properly. I am doing a multi version module, but loads requested version and later when I call a function which I exported in different version, loads another version of my module. How to avoid this?

```
Here is my set up.
I am having two versions 1.0 and 1.1
Structure of module files:
P:\PS1\MyModules\v1.0\TestMod\testMod.psd1
P:\PS1\MyModules\v1.0\TestMod\testMod.psm1
P:\PS1\MyModules\v1.1\TestMod\testMod.psd1
P:\PS1\MyModules\v1.1\TestMod\testMod.psm 

I added to $env:PSModulePath += ‘;P:\ps1\MyModules\v1.0;P:\ps1\MyModules\v1.1’

Here are my manifest files. Notice that I am exporting different set of functions.
v1.0\TestMod\testMod.psd1
@{
    RootModule        = 'testMod.psm1'
    ModuleVersion     = '1.0'
    Author            = 'First LastName'
    CompanyName       = 'XXX, LLC.'
    PowerShellVersion = '5.1'
    FunctionsToExport = @('f1','f2')
} 

v1.1\TestMod\testMod.psd1
@{
    RootModule        = 'testMod.psm1'
    ModuleVersion     = '1.1'
    Author            = 'First LastName'
    CompanyName       = 'XXX, LLC.'
    PowerShellVersion = '5.1'
    FunctionsToExport = @('f1','f3')
}
 
The following are my module files:

v1.0\TestMod\testMod.psm1. 
Please remember that output from this module goes in yellow color
Write-Host "Version 1.0" -f y


function f1 {
    Write-Host "F1 v1.0" -f y
}

function f2 {
    Write-Host "F2 v1.0" -f y
}  

function f3 {
    Write-Host "F3 v1.0" -f y
}  

v1.1\TestMod\testMod.psm1. 
Write-Host "Version 1.1"


function f1 {
    Write-Host "F1 v1.1"
}

function f2 {
    Write-Host "F2 v1.1"
}  

function f3 {
    Write-Host "F3 v1.1"
}  


My script looks like this:
Remove-Module testMod
Import-Module -Name testMod -RequiredVersion 1.1 -Verbose -Global

Get-Module testMod

'';'~'*30
f1     #exported in v1.0 and v1.1
f2     #exported on v1.0
f3     #exported in          v1.1

'~'*30;''

Get-Module testMod 


For version 1.1 I would expect output from f1 and f3 functions and failure on f2, but the real output is as follows. Pay attention to yellow strings.

VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'P:\ps1\MyModules\v1.0\testMod\testMod.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'P:\ps1\MyModules\v1.1\testMod\testMod.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'P:\ps1\MyModules\v1.1\testMod\testMod.psm1'.
Version 1.1
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'f1'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'f2'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'f3'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'f1'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'f3'.

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands     
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------     
Script     1.1        testMod                             {f1, f3}             

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
F1 v1.1
Version 1.0
F2 v1.0
F3 v1.1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Script     1.1        testMod                             {f1, f3}             
Script     1.0        TestMod                             {f1, f2}             
 

As you can see the first Get-Module output shows only module v1.1, but when I call f2 powershell loads version 1.0, in which this function is exported. And at the end the output from Get-Module shows two versions 1.0 and 1.1.
Please advise how to fix this situation?
```

Comment: Bring `f2` to the newer version of the module perhaps

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. When I added at the top of my script variable $PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference = "None" it stopped auto downloading other versions of my module.